# From .net how to I send many “batches” of SQL to Sql-Server without lots of round trips?

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net

We have code that reads in a set of SQL script file, and after doing some processing on them splits them into batches by finding the “GO” keyword and then sends each batch to Sql Server using a separate SqlCommon.

Is there a better way of doing this so we:

- Don’t have as many round trips
- Never have SQL Server waiting for the next batch
- Run faster.

(The batches are mostly creating tables, index, views and stored procs.   Speed is an issue as our integration tests calls the code often.   The sql-server common line tools may not be installed on the machine that is running this code.)

Comment: Is the round-trip really significant w.r.t. the database ops? I guess you've already arranged as much as possible into each batch?

Comment: @Rup, combining the batches would take lots of time hand-editing the SQL.   I am trying to find a quick gain that gives us some benifit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest solution is in fact splitting on GO. However, another alternative is to use the SQL Management Objects (SMO) and send the entire script to SQL Server in one fell swoop as if you were using Management Studio.

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ connectionStringName ].ConnectionString;
using ( var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection( connectionString ) )
{
    var server = new Server( new ServerConnection( sqlConnection ) );
    server.ConnectionContext.Connect();
    server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery( sqlFileContents );
    server.ConnectionContext.Disconnect();
}
```

[SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx)

Comment: Be very careful splitting on GO: As soon as you have multi-line comments containing GO lines (i.e. multi-batch scripts that are partially commented out) all hell will break loose. If you need to handle this type of case, best to go with SMO.

Comment: Another note on this answer - regardless of whether you split on GO or use SMO, there **will** be many round-trips: SMO also submits each batch to the server separately.

Answer (score 3):

2 ideas...

Package the script and modify it to be runnable as a dynamic SQL snippet.  Upload the entire batch in a stream using nvarchar(max) and run it using sp_executesql on the server side.  Since you control it for integration testing, dynamic SQL is not much of an issue.

Upload the entire batch to the server as a nvarchar(max).  Save the file on the SQL Server machine using xp_cmdshell or CLR or other.  Again using xp_cmdshell, use sqlcmd to run the script file.

With any sort of batching, you lose some way of identifying exactly where it broke, since you are automating integration testing after all.

Comment: Knowing the about broken bits of SQL is of value to us, so we would have to have the "server side" procesing of the batch give good errors.