# In .Net, how to execute a SQL Server script against an instance?

Tags: .net, sql-server, database-connection

I know there is a class `system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand` that can execute a **batch** at a time. Since I have a lot if SQL Server scripts (in which there is some **GO** key words in it), I need to find a way that can throw this script to SQL Server for executing. How to do this ? Thanks.

---

Edit:

Hi Enrico, thanks for the information you provided. The executenonquery method will return a int[] type. How can I get all the text result? For example, I have this SQL script called ***sql.sql***.

```
PRINT 'blah blah blah';
GO
SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS instance;
```

When I use sqlcmd to execute it, I get the following result.

```
C:\TEMP>sqlcmd -S (local)\instance1 -U a -P a -i sql.sql
blah blah blah
instance

-------------------------------------------------------------------
THESIMPSONS\INSTANCE1


(1 rows affected)

C:\TEMP>
```

How can I get the similar result using SMO or ADO.NET classes? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.executenonquery.aspx) method part of the [SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) API will correctly execute T-SQL scripts that contain *multiple batches* separated by the `GO` keyword.

As a side note, you can even decide to use your *own batch separator* by setting the [ServerConnection.BatchSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.batchseparator.aspx) property, which by default is `"GO"`.

If your script returns multiple result sets that you wish to get back in your application, you can use either the [ServerConnection.ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms199426.aspx) or the [ServerConnection.ExecuteWithResults](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms199352.aspx) method. However, keep in mind that those methods [*do not* support T-SQL scripts with multiple batches](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/404497/error-when-using-executewithresults-smo-serverconnection-object-method). At this point you have a couple of options:

- **Split the script** on the `"GO"` separator into multiple strings, each containing a *single batch*, and execute them through one of the methods mentioned above.
- **Invoke `SQLCMD`** from your code by spawning a new process and passing the script to execute as a parameter.

Comment: There is a comment on those overloads: "The sqlCommand parameter contains a single Transact-SQL statement." - if this works as you describe, then the documentation is misleading.

Comment: @MarkGravell: You're right, the documentation is misleading, but it definitely works.

Comment: I've used this method to programmatically execute T-SQL scripts that would normally run with `SQLCMD`. Check out the remarks for [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms199328.aspx).

Comment: @MarcGravell I have to agree that the documentation could be clearer when it comes to batch processing.

Comment: Hi Enrico, thanks for answering. I've edited my question, please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Enrico. I'll go with native SQLCMD.

Comment: @Yousui Cool. Did that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

What about SMO as suggested in the selected answer in this question: [From .net how to I send many “batches” of SQL to Sql-Server without lots of round trips?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593820/from-net-how-to-i-send-many-batches-of-sql-to-sql-server-without-lots-of-roun)

Answer (score 0):

The `SqlCommand` can execute more than one statement in one go as long as the statement is wrapped in `BEGIN` and `END`, like a stored procedure. I've done that, but I think only data manipulation commands are allowed.

There are the [SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) which may be able to do what you want, as they can also be used to issue data definition commands.